# Why can't I add heroku as a remote from my EC2 instance?

Tags: git, heroku, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 ubuntu instance. I cloned a sample node project into it, created a heroku project, (seemingly successfully) added SSH keys, but when I try to add heroku as a remote from my instance I get this error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-etc:/home/node-js-sample$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample.git (push)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-etc:/home/node-js-sample$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:pure-beyond-9756.git
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
```

The aforementioned .git/config contains the following:

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
url = https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample.git
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

If I pop over to my heroku dashboard, everything is fine there.
Why am I getting this permission denied error, and how to resolve? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you installed Heroku toolbelt

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Try to add Heroku's remote with the toolbelt's command:

```
$ heroku git:remote -a pure-beyond-9756
```

see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

for similar *Permission denied* problem check this topic: [problem on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258288/trouble-setting-up-git-error-could-not-lock-config-file)

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up creating a new EC2 instance and deploying to heroku worked fine on that instance, but this points to some useful tools/references